Не отображаются установленные плагины
скачала Sublime Text 3. Начала искать настройки в YouTube и в Google. Начала настраивать и все норм, кроме плагинов...
Тут у меня появилась проблема с отображением установленных плагинов. В плане: я их установила, они установились, но их нигде нет. Не в папках, не в самом Sublime Text 3.
Я попробовала переустановить IDLE - не помогло
Я попробовала дважды и трижды переустановить плагины - не помогло
Если у кого-то была такая проблема, помогите пожалуйста! В интернете ответов на этот вопрос вообще нет, либо есть но я их удачно прошла
